# Do I still need to use mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification in an App that use child-parent NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperationqueue

According to [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification%3a), we have the following:

> When you save changes in a context, the changes are only committed “one store up.” If you save a child context, changes are pushed to its parent. Changes are not saved to the persistent store until the root context is saved. (A root managed object context is one whose parent context is nil.) In addition, a parent does not pull changes from children before it saves. You must save a child context if you want ultimately to commit the changes.

My data model roughly consists of the following `NSManagedObject` hierarchy:

```
Category <---->> Feed <---->> Post
```

My application, an RSS Reader, uses the following:

- a "root" `NSManagedObjectContext` with a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` Concurrency type. I use this MOC to persist my changes to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.
- a "main" `NSManagedObjectContext` with a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` Concurrency type. I use this MOC to feed my GUI.
- a "local" `NSManagedObjectContext` with a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` Concurrency type. I use this MOC when creating batches of new Posts objects.

So, my questions are:

1. When I save my `localMOC`, does it automatically propagate to my `mainMOC` ? or do I still have to observe `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` from the `localMOC`and manually merge both MOCs with `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`?
2. Until yesterday, the batch import was taking place in an external `DBOperation <NSOperation>` context which was send to an `NSOperationQueue`, how would the synchronisation occur here? Do I have to pass the `mainMOC` as a parameter to `DBOperation` in order to use it as each `localMOC`'s parent?
3. I placed the batch routine back in my `MainViewController` but I am not sure it was a good idea. Should I stick to a `NSOperationQueue` like before or does the current `[localMOC performBlock:^{ ... }];` structure offer me decent background processing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What are the relationships between "root", "main" & local. Presumably "main" and "local" have the "root" as their parent?

Comment: Also, this is a good read: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Comment: Hey Mike, I read that article and its "Asynchronous Saving" paragraph is what inspired me: ``root`` is ``main``'s parent whilst ``main`` is ``local``'s parent. In this article, ``root``'d be ``writerMOC``. I am just not sure how I could deploy these in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problems by implementing my own save routine:

```
[_localMOC performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSError *errLoc=nil;

    if (![self.mainMOC obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[[[_mainMOC insertedObjects]     arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[_mainMOC updatedObjects]]] error:&errLoc]) {
    NSLog(@" ... ");
    }

    if (![_localMOC save:&errLoc]) {
      NSLog(@" ... ");
    }
    [_mainMOC performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *errMain=nil;
        if (![_mainMOC save:&errMain]) {
            NSLog(@" ... ");
        }
    }]
}];
```

Note that `_mainMOC` is being observed from the `AppDelegate` and will have its changes asynchronically persisted to disk by his `_saveMOC` parent.